# Getting manager & managers manager number in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have below table in oracle

```
EMPNO   ENAME   MGR 
1       A       1 
2       B       1 
3       C       2 
4       D       3 
5       F       1 
6       G       3 
7       H       6
```

I need to pass a EMPNO and it should give me manger id and if manager has another manager it should give me there id's too in the same field.

For example, If I pass empno = 7 then the output should be 6,3,2,1.

Comment: will you only ever have 4 levels of supervision, or is it abitrary-depth? for fixed-dept, just self-join as many times as you have layers. for abitrary, you'll need a recursive query.

Comment: levels are not fixed.

Comment: Marc,                                                                                                                       I wrote below query but it doesn't seems to work...sorry I have never used recursive query                                                                                             SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,MGR,LEVEL
FROM EMP
WHERE EMPNO = '7'
CONNECT BY PRIOR EMPNO = MGR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query, I used finally for the actual results

```sql
SELECT ENAME, 
       CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE Cycle,
       LEVEL, 
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ENAME, '/') Path
FROM   EMP_DEMO
START WITH empno = '7'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR MGR = EMPNO;
```

You always have to take the max level record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`connect by`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) syntax to create a hierarchical query:

```
SELECT     mgr
FROM       emp
START WITH empno = 7
CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = mgr
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, when I run above query it just gives me 6 as output.